# How to get date and time in Javascript not UTC

Tags: javascript

I am just trying to get date and time in the format below. It just seems very hard and complicated in JS.

2019-06-27 01:06:34.947

British time, date, hour minutes and seconds are the most important, milliseconds not essential.

Whenever I try, I get the time in UTC, I also do not need PM/AM etc shown.

```js
var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString(undefined, {
  day: '2-digit',
  month: '2-digit',
  year: 'numeric'
  //hour: '2-digit',
  //minute: '2-digit',
  //second: '2-digit' 
})
console.log('today', today)


var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit'
})
console.log('time', time)

//var date = new Date();
//var timestamp = date.getTime();

var mytime = today + " " + time;
console.log('mytime', mytime)

//var tt = new Date().toLocaleString().replace(",","").replace(/:.. /," ");

var currentdate = new Date();
var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/" +
  (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
  currentdate.getFullYear() +
  currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
  currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" +
  currentdate.getSeconds();
console.log('datetime', datetime)

X = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
Y = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', {
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric"
});
mynew = X + " " + Y;
console.log('mynew', mynew)
```

I expect to see 2019-06-27 01:06:34.947 or 27-06-2019 01:06:34.947

Comment: If you want a _YYYY-MM-DD_ date format, why are you formatting `datetime` as _DD/MM/YYYY_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your best option to format a local `Date` instance as *YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS* would be to build the string yourself

```js
const today = new Date()
const formatted = 
    `${
      today.getFullYear()
    }-${
      String(today.getMonth()+1).padStart(2, '0')
    }-${
      String(today.getDay()).padStart(2, '0')
    } ${
      String(today.getHours()).padStart(2, '0')
    }:${
      String(today.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0')
    }:${
      String(today.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0')
    }`

// this just displays it
document.querySelector('pre').textContent = formatted
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Libraries like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) make this sort of thing much easier.

```js
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. Is it possible to have this in just pure Js non web code ? Where i am coding is not a web based system.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. The date string part of my answer **is** pure JS. The DOM part is just for showing the result in the Stack Snippet